# Comparing mclust() and k-means centroids

Tags: r, clustering

I have some code that looks for clusters in x,y data. To check the number of clusters I use, I want to get the BIC. This is not possible (easily) using `kmeans()`, and so I've switched to the [mclust package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html). Specifically, I'm trying to replace `kmeans()` from the R stats package, with `Mclust()` from the mclust package.

Using `Mclust()` requires me to specify which model should be used for the clustering. According to `?Mclust`, the following models can be used in `Mclust()`:

```
univariate mixture      
"E"  =   equal variance (one-dimensional)
"V"  =   variable variance (one-dimensional)
multivariate mixture        
"EII"    =   spherical, equal volume
"VII"    =   spherical, unequal volume
"EEI"    =   diagonal, equal volume and shape
"VEI"    =   diagonal, varying volume, equal shape
"EVI"    =   diagonal, equal volume, varying shape
"VVI"    =   diagonal, varying volume and shape
"EEE"    =   ellipsoidal, equal volume, shape, and orientation
"EEV"    =   ellipsoidal, equal volume and equal shape
"VEV"    =   ellipsoidal, equal shape
"VVV"    =   ellipsoidal, varying volume, shape, and orientation
single component        
"X"  =   univariate normal
"XII"    =   spherical multivariate normal
"XXI"    =   diagonal multivariate normal
"XXX"    =   ellipsoidal multivariate normal
```

I'm presuming that k-means in stats is a "spherical, unequal volume" model, ie. to get `k-means(x = data, centers = 6)` to match `mclust()`, I should use `mclust(data, G = 6, modelNames = c("VII"))`.

However, in the limited tests I've done, this gives different cluster centroids. The example below uses 6 clusters with some test data. The centroids obtained through each method are shown.

[image]

Can anyone confirm which `mclust()` model is equivalent to `kmeans()`?

Comment: I doubt that there can be any equivalence. `mclust` presents normal-model-based EM clustering, wherease k-means is not dependent on any type of the distribution, it is not model-based. These are different algorithms.

Comment: I hadn't realised/noticed that `Mclust()` uses gaussian mixture modeling. Therefore there's no way the two methods are really comparable. I'll leave this question here for people that make the same mistake...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gaussian Mixture Modeling is not the same as k-means.

None of the models has a 1:1 correspondence to k-means. The closes is probably

```
"EII"    =   spherical, equal volume
```

but Mclust will still use a *soft* assignment, whereas k-means uses a *hard* assignment. There is a closer relationship between EII and fuzzy c-means (although I don't think they are the same either, due to different weighting functions).

Also note that k-means is commonly randomly seeded, so different runs of k-means will often yield different results, too!

Comment: I completely missed the bit about `Mclust()` using GMM. If I'd seen that (or not been so infatuated with the fact that it reported BIC), I'd never have posted this question...